# Office.js | excel add-in | redux dispatch action is not working on excel desktop

Tags: excel, reactjs, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I am working on a Excel Add-In using Office.js. Used redux to dispatch actions.
Add in is working in all browsers using office 365 but dispatch action is not working on desktop excel.

Scenario:

1. Open Excel load add-in.
2. Click on continue button from task pan. (used redux dispatch to redirect to route not working)

Below is the code:
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store, { history } from './store';
import routes from './routes';

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router routes={routes} history={history} />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

routes.js

```
import { SocialLogin } from 'pages';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: LandingPage,
    },
    {
        path: '/social-login',
        exact: true,
        component: SocialLogin,
    },
];
export default routes;
```

On Landing Page has button and on click of button calling below function:

```
const onNextClick = () => {
        props.onButtonClicked(`/social-login`);
    };
```

On onButtonClicked fuction present in my Action file which i used using mapDispatchToProps connect wrapper.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
...bindActionCreators(
    {
        onButtonClicked,
    },
    dispatch,
),
```

});

and onButtonClicked function which just push the path like below:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
export const onButtonClicked = redirectUrl => dispatch => {
    dispatch(push(path));
};
```

**The above implementation is working on all browsers.**

But looks like getting below error on Desktop excel:

[image]

can someone please help to check the issue.. spend lots of time.